# Is this Javascript Regex? Not able to produce mentioned result.

Tags: javascript

Given a page of content with alphanumeric words, and a search phrase of N words, write an algorithm that will return the shortest snippet of content that contains all N words in any order.

Example: The George Washington Bridge in New York City is one of the oldest bridges ever constructed. It is now being remodeled because the bridge is a landmark. City officials say that the landmark bridge effort will create a lot of new jobs in the city.

Search Terms: Landmark City Bridge

Result: bridge is a landmark. City

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also **"Is this Javascript Regex?"** What javascript? I don't see any source code. Just a description of what you want.

Comment: You need to ask if non-search terms can be present: term term non-term term, or if the search terms must be contiguous.

Comment: it seems from the example that the words need not be contiguous. Op: what's the shortest snippet? Number of characters, or words?

Comment: The question really needs to be rephrased. Right now, it looks like someone copied a test question verbatim.

Answer (score -1):

1. Determine the position of each occurence of each word in a list, sorted by position.
2. For each occurrence at pos n in the list, determine how far ahead in the list one must step to have seen all words. You'd probably use an array of booleans correlating to whether a word has been seen between n and n+i.
3. Then you can determine the length of the substring from the start of word n to the end of word n+i.
4. If the length of this candidate solution is less than the previous candidate, store it. Continue from step 2.

Comment: Feel free to explain any down votes, and I'll work towards an improved answer? Cheers